# How to swap camera angles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, video-sequence-editor, camera, video

Consider a cube, a wall and two cameras (A and B).The cube moves toward the wall and crashes through it. Camera A tracks the cube as it moves toward the wall at which point the camera view / angle swaps out Camera B which records the cube crashing through the wall after which the view angle is again passed back to Camera A which shows the cube proceeding forward after the crash. I set up multiple cameras and switched them in different strips of the Video Sequence Editor, however, the playback freezes after playing the second strip.
How do i fix this? Or am i doing something wrong here?
Also, how do I render this video considering the above and the fact that the wall is on another Layer.

**UPDATE :**

[image]

Comment: How is this different from your other question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/how-swap-views-between-multiple-cameras

Comment: @RayMairlot  'cause, I'm able to add multiple 'strips' effectively changing the camera angle, but when the slider reaches the third strip the video is just frozen, doesn't play beyond that point ... also, I'm looking to extend / slow down a camera's output

Comment: Then I suggest refining your question as most of it seems to be focused on asking how to do it as opposed to what you just explained to me.

Comment: @RayMairlot how's this?

Comment: When you added the VSE scene strips was the scene the same length as it is now that you've finished animating it? If you added a scene strip THEN changed the length of the 3D scene afterwards, it will be the wrong length and will freeze at the end. To fix this just delete the short strip and add it again.

Comment: @3pointedit I see