# Blender renders the same camera view even after camera is deleted!

Tags: rendering, camera

I have Blender 2.8 and setup 3 cameras for my animation. I want to render animation of one camera at a time in separated output files, like: Hit render to render camera 1 save the animation, then change the active camera, hit render again and so on - but blender always render camera 1 view.

I set a different camera as active, change the camera 1 location to camera 2 location and even delete camera 1 from the scene but it still render camera 1 view no matter what!!

I don't want to render every camera in a single animation, I want to render only one camera of those...

My setup:
[image: my setup]

Render:
[image: Render]

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to set it up as a sequence and switch cameras with a marker. I think this question is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/how-swap-views-between-multiple-cameras

Comment: It's the scene camera which is going to be rendered *(Properties Area > Scene > Camera)*.

Comment: @brockmann yes, I did change the camera there but still it doesn't render the selected camera view

Comment: Had the same issue and realized that I had a video clip in the sequencer that I forgot to delete, as well as still having "Compositing" and "Sequencer" checked under post processing.

Comment: Next, try to disable the compositor and the sequencer -> *Output Properties (Printer Icon) > Post Processing > Compositing / Sequencer*... I guess that's a template right? If my last guess doesn't solve your issue, ask the author. or share your file, otherwise it's just a waste of time.

Comment: @The_Machine & brockmann it works like a charm, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to set it up as a sequence and switch cameras with a marker. I think this question is a duplicate of [How swap views between multiple cameras?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/how-swap-views-between-multiple-cameras).

You can create markers on the timeline with the M key. Then select the camera you want to bind to that marker and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. As soon as your timeline reaches that marker the camera will switch. It is important that both the marker and the camera are selected.

So if you're doing stills, you'd only need however many frames as cameras that you have.

Edit: (select your camera and use CTRL+Num 0) ...

Comment: No, I don't want to render every camera in a single animation, I want to render only one camera of those..

Comment: Right, instead of choosing a video format when you render, choose an image format. It will give you each frame as a still image.

Comment: Does CTRL+NUM 0 not change your camera?