# There's no camera on the timeline in 2D animation

Tags: animation, 2d, timeline

I've clicked on all the options, but I can't find them. Let me know.[image]

Comment: I couldn't see it because I didn't have a keyframe. Try adding a keyframe.

Comment: Related?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72281/15543 particularly bind camera to marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to enter Object mode.
[image: Blender example : Camera Settings in 2D animation]

Comment: Hello, please add more info to your answer to help prevent it from getting deleted. Currently, it is rated as a "low-quality answer".

Comment: oho ok thank you

Comment: I could add more text but this would be useless as the answer is simple.