# Is there a problem in blender 2.92 to change active camera?

Tags: camera

I have the default camera with several key frames set for a video and had no problems.
Then I have added a new camera.001 and set it as active (I checked answers from "How can I make a camera the active one?" to make sure I did not forget anything stupid, and it is set as the active camera, I even added markers), but still whatever I do, the image rendered is still from the default camera. I did it in the past and never had this problem, so I'm wondering if this is a bug?

Comment: There's no known bug.  Please add your blend file to your post so we can check it and see if we notice anything you missed. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably Bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Camera to Marker <kbd>M</kbd> in Timeline ... ?

[image]

More about *[How swap views between multiple cameras?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72281/2214)*

Comment: If the answer solved your issue consider mark as Accepted so system is not pocking Question and others can see it from main list https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you keep site organised.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found my mistake. After I rendered my image sequence, I then added the image sequence in the video sequencer to render the animation. I left that image sequence there so the same image was always rendered. I removed the image sequence from the video sequencer and everything worked fine. Thanks for your help and sorry for the waste of time.